# Batch renaming files by removing specific characters before file extension?

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I am having a set of files in folders and sub-folders where I want to remove specific characters from files like below:

```
adjust_the_m.2_retainer_zh-cn.dita
assert_physical_presence_en-us.dita
back_up_the_server_configuration_es.dita
backplane_cable_routing_fr-fr.dita
```

I want to rename them as below:

```
adjust_the_m.2_retainer.dita
assert_physical_presence.dita
back_up_the_server_configuration.dita
backplane_cable_routing.dita
```

I want this in Command Prompt Batch.bat file.

Comment: Do you need the batch-script also to check all the subdirectories for other files with this name (or format), or it should just take the files as a list and then rename them?

Comment: I need a batch-script which can change file names in directories as well as sub-directories. Other files can also be:
adjust_the_m.2_retainer_zh-cn.dita
assert_physical_presence_en-us.ditamap
back_up_the_server_configuration_es.dita
backplane_cable_routing_fr-fr.ditaval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now final code is as below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.dita *.ditamap *.ditaval) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"
goto :eof

:process
set "file=%~1"
for %%b in (%file:_= %) do set last=_%%b
rem echo %last%
set "file=!file:%last%=!"
move "%~1%~2" "%file%%~2"
echo %file%%~2
```

Thanks for your help @Stephan!

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the last part (delimited with `_`) of the filename?
Take the name without extension (`%%~dpna`), get the last part, remove it from the filename (`set` variable substring replacement) and add the extension (`%%~xa`)

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.dita) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"
goto :eof

:process
set "file=%~1"
for %%b in (%file:_= %) do set last=_%%b
set "file=!file:%last%=!"
move "%~1%~2" "%file%%~2"
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not worked! Nothing was renamed using above Commands.

Comment: to rename, use the [ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) command, like `ren "%%a" " %file%%~2"` Attention: if you have already renamed filenames, it will remove another part of the name (e.g.: `adjust_the_m.2_retainer.dita` --> `adjust_the_m.2.dita`

Comment: I Created a Batch.bat file in which I inserted your commands as below:
`@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.dita) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"
goto :eof

:process
set "file=%~1"
for %%b in (%file:_= %) do set last=_%%b
rem echo %last%
set "file=!file:%last%=!"
ren "%%a" " %file%%~2"
echo %file%%~2`

I kept Batch.bat file and the files which I want to rename in same folder and double clicked the Batch.bat file. There were no changes in files names. Please check if I am missing something in my commands.

Comment: don't start it by doubleclicking. Open a command prompt window and start it from there. Then the window keeps open and you can read any messages.

Comment: It shows me error that **The system cannot find the file specified**

Comment: sorry, my fault. `Ren` does not support a path for the destination. Changed to use `move` instead.

Comment: I changed `ren` to `move` and now I get error as **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**. Check if below commands are correct in Batch.bat file.
`@echo off`
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
`for /r %%a in (*.dita) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"`
`goto :eof`

`:process`
`set "file=%~1"`
`for %%b in (%file:_= %) do set last=_%%b`
`rem echo %last%`
`set "file=!file:%last%=!"`
`move "%%a" " %file%%~2"`
`echo %file%%~2`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is working now on *.dita files. Can you please let me know how I should make it work on *.dita, *.ditamap and *.ditaval files? Should I use `for /r %%a in (*.dita*) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"`

Comment: `for /r %%a in (*.dita*) do ...` or `for /r %%a in (*.dita *.ditamap *.ditaval) do ...`

Comment: Above both commands are working good.  
Now final code is as below:  
`@echo off`  
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`  
`for /r %%a in (*.dita *.ditamap *.ditaval) do call :process "%%~dpna" "%%~xa"`  
`goto :eof`  
  
`:process`  
`set "file=%~1"`  
`for %%b in (%file:_= %) do set last=_%%b`  
`rem echo %last%`  
`set "file=!file:%last%=!"`  
`move "%~1%~2" "%file%%~2"`  
`echo %file%%~2`  

Thanks for your help!